# XMLHttpRequest cannot load file.js Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

If I try to run my Cordova app I get the following error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///android_asset/www/smp/logon/ui/resources/sap/ui/thirdparty/jquery-mobile-custom.js. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.", source: file:///android_asset/www/smp/logon/ui/iab.html (0)

I have whitelisted everything with:

```
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="null" />
```

in `res/xml/config.xml`. How can I fix this?

I also tried it without the origin null, but it does not work either.

Comment: Problem seems to be the ```file:///``` urls. CORS requests need to authorize the Origin header and cannot do so on ```file:///``` urls. Try setting up a server instead.

Comment: This cannot be done. I can only use these local files.